# "From time to time, I do my homework, and I will get distracted by my phone." - does this tell something that keeps happening?

Tags: tense, usage

**Example 1**

> (1) "From time to time, I came home from work, and I would see my brother watching a movie."

> (2) "From time to time, whenever I came home from work, I would see my brother watching a movie."

I want to say something that kept happening in the past. Which one to use?

**Example 2**

> (3) "From time to time, I do my homework, and I will get distracted by my phone."

> (4) "From time to time, whenever I do my homework, I will get distracted by my phone."

I want to say something that keeps happening. Which one to use?

Comment: I assume you're trying to say it *often* happened during some period in the past, not that it happened *every time you came home* during that period. So use your *second* phrasing, but change ***whenever*** to just ***when*** (and lose one if not both commas). If it's ***still*** happening, change ***came*** to ***come*** and remove the word ***would*** from your second example. *Never* include ***will*** in such contexts.

Comment: (1) and (3) make it sound as though you only come home from work, or do your homework, occasionally.

Comment: @KateBunting In a case where I do my homework occasionally, can I say, "From time to time, I do my homework, and I get distracted by my phone"? And for past tense, can I say, "From time to time, I did my homework, and I would get distracted by my phone"?

Comment: Well, that version sounds as though you only do homework occasionally and you get distracted _every time_. A native speaker would say something like "From time to time, when I'm doing my homework, I get distracted by my phone."